# can not create the xml file using jdom

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.jdom2.Attribute; 
import org.jdom2.Document; 
import org.jdom2.Element; 
import org.jdom2.output.Format; 
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;


try {
    Element FICHADAS = new Element("FICHADAS");
    Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
    doc.setRootElement(FICHADAS);
    Element fichada = new Element("fichada");
    fichada.addContent(new Element("N_Terminal").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Tarjeta").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Fecha").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Hora").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Causa").setText("XX"));
    doc.getRootElement().addContent(fichada);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\file.xml"));
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

i try to find the file.xml in C:\ but is not here and I don't know why, and the console show me that: The element "FICHADAS" could not be added as the root of the document: The Content already has an existing parent document

//NEW
I was thinking, and now i only need to add the new fichadas to the existing document, not need to create it every time that i opened the program.

Comment: Can you add the `import` statements, so we can see which objects do you use?

Comment: no, how can I add the import statements?¿?

Comment: The `import` statement are the firrst lines of your code. why you can not add it?  from wich package is `Element`, `Document`, `XMLOutputter ?

Comment: import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
doc.setRootElement(FICHADAS);
```

because you set the root element here:

```
Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! and the last question in this line:
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("C:\file.xml"));
seems that the program can not take the path because the "rare" characters, how can i do it?

Comment: You have to escape the backslash: `xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("C:\\file.xml")); `